# Android object value changed when resume

Tags: android, android-activity, onresume

I got a VERY STRANGE situation...(to me)

For example, 2 objects,

1 is an activity member boolean called isInPage,

2 is a static bitmap object called bmpPhoto.

When I get into my own activity called FacebookShareActivity

isInPage will be true until I quit this activity,

bmpPhoto will be given a picture.

After onCreare() and onResume(), there is no any code running, until user click some GUI.

What I did is close screen by press hardware power button, and maybe wait 5 or 10 minutes.

OK, now I press porwe again to wake phone up, unlock screen,

and my FacebookShareActivity goes back to front.

And I click my GUI button to check variable value via Logcat, it says:

isInPage=false;
And I forget bmpPhoto's value, but on my GUI, the photo just gone,

 not displayed anymore...

How is this happen ?

And it just not happen every time after I do that......

What if I override onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) and 

onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) ?

Will it help ?

And what about the bitmap object ?

Still don't know how is that happen...

Did I miss something ?

I really need your help, please everyone~

Following is part of my code, quite long...
The "isPageRunning" and "bmp" changed sometime when back from desktop, but not everytime.

```
public class FacebookShareActivity extends Activity
{
  private Bundle b=null;
  private Bitmap bmp=null;
  private boolean isFacebookWorking=false;
  private boolean isPageRunning=true; //This value sometime changed when back from desktop, but not every time

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    Log.i(Constants.TAG, "ON Facebook Share create......");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.facebook_share);
    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
  }

  private void initUI()
  {
    btnBack=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
    btnBack.setOnClickListener(new ButtonClickHandler());

    formImage=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.form_image);
    formImage.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

    btnShare=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnShare);
    btnShare.setOnClickListener(new ButtonClickHandler());

    txtIntroText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtIntroText);
    txtIntroText.setOnClickListener(new ButtonClickHandler());
    txtIntroText.setText(getUploadInImageText());

    photo=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.photo);
    bmp=Constants.PROFILE.getName().getPhoto();
    if(bmp!=null)
    {photo.setImageBitmap(bmp);} //bmp wouldn't be null, it filled by some other activity before
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume()
  {
    super.onResume();
    Log.i(Constants.TAG, "Trying to set UI on resume...");
    b=getIntent().getExtras();
    // ...
    // ... Get some String value passed from prev activity

    facebook=new Facebook("123456789012345"); //Test
    asyncFacebook=new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);

    initUI();
    System.gc();
  }

  @Override
  public void onBackPressed()
  {
    Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Activity receive back key...");
    lockButtons(false);
    return;
  }

  private void lockButtons(boolean b)
  {
    if(isPageRunning)
    {
      btnBack.setClickable(!b);
      btnShare.setClickable(!b);
    }
  }

  private class DelayReleaseKey implements Runnable
  {
    public void run()
    {
      try{Thread.sleep(10000);}
      catch(InterruptedException ie){}
      handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }
  }

  private class ButtonClickHandler implements OnClickListener
  {
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
      if(v==btnBack)
      {
        if(isFacebookWorking)
        {ShowAlertDialog(Constants.MESSAGE_FACEBOOK_WORK);}
        else
        {
          lockButtons(true);
          formImage=null;
          photo=null;
          b=null;
          facebook=null;
          isPageRunning=false;
          Intent intent=new Intent(FacebookShareActivity.this, PracticeListActivity.class);
          startActivity(intent);
          FacebookShareActivity.this.finish();
          overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left,android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
        }
      }
      if(v==btnShare)
      {
        lockButtons(true);
        facebookLogin();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now I know i must override onSaveInstanceState, onRestoreInstanceState.
They can help me to save variable like String, int, boolean...
What about Bitmap ?
And what if my variable is static ?

Comment: RRTW, look at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Comment: where are you setting the boolean and image? Is it onCreate? Can you also put some code snippet?

Comment: We need to see some code.  It sounds like you are not persisting the state of your `Activity`, so that when it is killed and restarted it no longer has its previous state.  Post the code for your `Activity` so we can check.

Answer (score 0):

Now try again.

```
public class FacebookShareActivity extends Activity
{
  private Bundle b=null;
  private static Bitmap bmp=null;
  private static boolean isFacebookWorking=false;
  private static boolean isPageRunning=true; //This value sometime changed when back from desktop, but not every time

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    Log.i(Constants.TAG, "ON Facebook Share create......");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.facebook_share);
    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
  }

  private void initUI()
  {
    btnBack=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
    btnBack.setOnClickListener(new ButtonClickHandler());

    formImage=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.form_image);
    formImage.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

    btnShare=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnShare);
    btnShare.setOnClickListener(new ButtonClickHandler());

    txtIntroText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtIntroText);
    txtIntroText.setOnClickListener(new ButtonClickHandler());
    txtIntroText.setText(getUploadInImageText());

    photo=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.photo);
    bmp=Constants.PROFILE.getName().getPhoto();
    if(bmp!=null)
    {photo.setImageBitmap(bmp);} //bmp wouldn't be null, it filled by some other activity before
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume()
  {
    super.onResume();
    isPageRunning = true;
    Log.i(Constants.TAG, "Trying to set UI on resume...");
    b=getIntent().getExtras();
    // ...
    // ... Get some String value passed from prev activity

    facebook=new Facebook("123456789012345"); //Test
    asyncFacebook=new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);

    initUI();
    System.gc();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPause()
  {
        isPageRunning = false;
  }


  @Override
  public void onBackPressed()
  {
    Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Activity receive back key...");
    lockButtons(false);
    return;
  }

  private void lockButtons(boolean b)
  {
    if(isPageRunning)
    {
      btnBack.setClickable(!b);
      btnShare.setClickable(!b);
    }
  }

  private class DelayReleaseKey implements Runnable
  {
    public void run()
    {
      try{Thread.sleep(10000);}
      catch(InterruptedException ie){}
      handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }
  }

  private class ButtonClickHandler implements OnClickListener
  {
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
      if(v==btnBack)
      {
        if(isFacebookWorking)
        {ShowAlertDialog(Constants.MESSAGE_FACEBOOK_WORK);}
        else
        {
          lockButtons(true);
          formImage=null;
          photo=null;
          b=null;
          facebook=null;
          isPageRunning=false;
          Intent intent=new Intent(FacebookShareActivity.this, PracticeListActivity.class);
          startActivity(intent);
          FacebookShareActivity.this.finish();
          overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left,android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
        }
      }
      if(v==btnShare)
      {
        lockButtons(true);
        facebookLogin();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For primitive values, you should use `onSaveInstanceState`. For restoring you can use `onRestoreInstanceState` or you can some code in `onCreate` like this:

```
if(savedInstanceState != null) {
  // restore old state
} else {
  // a fresh start
}
```

Now for restoring objects like `Bitmap` if they are not expensive to create and doesn't make your UI sluggish, create them again on restore. If you do not want to that then use `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance` and code will look like this:

```
@Override
public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance () {
  return bmp;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
  if
  bmp = (Bitmap)getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
}
```

WARNING: This api is deprecate, you might use it on old platforms. I put it here for illustration purpose. The new way to do this is more involving.

Here is detailed ref:

[getLastNonConfigurationInstance](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getLastNonConfigurationInstance%28%29)

[onRetainNonConfigurationInstance](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRetainNonConfigurationInstance%28%29)

Comment: I still don't know clearly about your post (sorry I'm not very well in english, but I'll try to follow you up), but now I think is...When other APP asked for more RAM, and android OS is cleaning RAM that my activity used, will I know about that? For example, will onLowMemory() be called ? I think it should be, but not sure...

Comment: Yes you can come to know about that. You have to use `BroadcastRecievers` and try to catch `ACTION_DEVICE_STORAGE_LOW` Here is the ref: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_DEVICE_STORAGE_LOW http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html